# What is the bottom type?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, curry-howard

In wikipedia, the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) is simply defined as "the type that has no values". However, if `b` is this empty type, then the product type `(b,b)` has no values either, but seems different from `b`. I agree bottom is uninhabited, but I don't think this property suffices to define it.

By the [Curry-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), bottom is associated to mathematical falsity. Now there is a logical principle stating that from False follows any proposition. By Curry-Howard, that means the type `forall a. bottom -> a` is inhabited, ie there exists a family of functions `f :: forall a. bottom -> a`.

What are those functions `f` ? Do they help define bottom, maybe as the infinite product of all types `forall a. a` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In Math**

Bottom is **a** type that has no value. That is : any empty type can play the bottom role.

Those `f :: forall a . Bottom -> a` functions are the empty functions. "empty" in the set theoretical definition of functions.

**In Programming**

Dedicating a concrete empty type to have it as bottom by a programming language base library is for convenience. Readability and compatibility of code benefits from everyone using the same empty type as bottom.

**In Haskell**

Let us refer to them with the more friendly names "Bottom" -> "Void", "f" -> "absurd".

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
data Void
```

This definition does not contain any constructors => an instance of it can not be created => it is empty.

```
absurd :: Bottom -> a
absurd = \ case {}
```

In the case expression we do not have to handle any cases because there are none.

They are already [defined in package `base`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Void.html)

Comment: I see 3 kinds of formulas in propositional calculus. 1) Tautologies, that are true in every interpretation in a Heyting algebra. 2) Formulas which negations are tautologies, they are false in every Heyting interpretations. 3) Formulas which values depend on the interpretation. By Curry-Howard cases 2 and 3 both correspond to empty types. However I reckon that case 2 should be singled out among empty types : only those types deserve to be called bottom.